# Safari on IOS window dragging and styling problem

Tags: html, css, ios

When I view my web page in safari on the IPad or IPhone I can touch and drag left to right and the entire window will be dragged around showing the grey background behind the window. [Here](http://yakkstr.com/test.html) is my page.

However, most sites I go to don't do anything when I touch and drag left to right. [Here](http://www.multitasked.net/2011/jun/27/hacked-gmail-google-account/) is an example.

What are they doing to prevent the dragging? Also, on my page, once you've dragged the window to the left you'll see a white space at the edge of the green background at the top. How do I get rid of that? Shouldn't the div cover the entire width of the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

There ya go! You're going to have to make your design work at that zoom though. Also playing with scales gives different results. Good luck with iOS web design!

Comment: You should replace colon with komma.